# LWUIT Table Layout embedded TextAreas

Tags: java-me, lwuit

my goal is to display a Table through parsing an XML file.

I'm using a SAX Parser and the content has **multirows** and I want
the table **width to fit** to the display. Of course Y_AXIS scrolling would be ok.

Right now, I'm using the *HTMLTableModel* of src/com/sun/lwuit/html/ and it's corresponding *HTMLTable*. For this I declared it's methods public so I can access them. This works fine so far. This allows me to declare tables without knowing their size prematurely.

To allow multirows, I'm embedding TextAreas in the Cells.

Now the problem: The HTMLTable t needs `t.setScrollableY(true)`, or else not all rows are shown.

This causes the table to be a bit to large in X direction, so the right border isn't shown.
Also the bottom border isn't shown all the time.

The **container** in which the table is embedded has **BorderLayout.Y_AXIS**.
Things I tried:
`t.setPreferredW(mainContainer.getLayoutWidth());` This does reduce the size of the table, but then the table doesn't show all it's rows, like without `t.setScrollableY(true).`

`t.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))` this causes an `java/lang/ClassCastException`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Excerpt from my code:

```
} else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("td")) {

                    if (sb.length() > 0) {
                        String sbt = new String(sb);
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                        TextArea c = new TextArea(sbt);
                        c.setEditable(false);
                        c.getStyle().setFont(smallFont);
                        table.addCell(c, false, null);
                    }
                } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("tr")) {
                    debugPrint("Row closed.");
                    table.commitRow();
                } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("table")) {
                    HTMLTable t = new HTMLTable(table);
                    //without scrollable Y not all table rows are shown
                    t.setScrollableY(true);
                    //t.setPreferredW(screenWidth);
                    //this is verboten.
                    t.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                    mainContainer.addComponent(t);
                    tableBool = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the layout of the table from table layout otherwise it will not be a table.

It should be possible to get the table to fill the width of a parent BoxLayout_Y by assigning width percentages to table columns up to 100% e.g. for a 3 column table return assign 33, 33 & 44.

This can be achieved by subclassing table and overriding the method:

```
protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
    TableLayout.Constraint c = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
    c.setWidthPercentage(whateverYouWant);
    return c;
}
```